# Which is more powerful??DFA or NFA?

Tags: automata, dfa, nfa

NFA is similar to DFA except following additional features:

1. Null (or ε) move is allowed i.e., it can move forward without reading symbols.
2. Ability to transit to any number of states for a particular input.
   However, these above features don’t add any power to NFA. If we compare both in terms of power, both are equivalent.

Is this statement correct?If so,then what is the need of NFAs when we already have DFAs??

Comment: Can every NFA be converted to a DFA? If so, what does the resulting automaton look like?

Comment: Yes every NFA can be converted to DFA .     And in what sense do you mean that how does resulting automaton look like??

Comment: What does an equivalent NFA and DFA look like? Why might this make some problems 'only realistically expressible as an NFA'?

Comment: Visit this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/automata_theory/ndfa_to_dfa_conversion.htm) ,you could see how state diagrams of the both differ but both can be treated as equivalent.

Comment: Well, since leading the horse doesn't work.. try reading https://www.quora.com/Why-is-NFA-used-when-we-already-have-DFA-Is-it-because-NFA-is-easier-to-create-and-then-we-can-convert-back-to-DFA "..it's always possible to find an equivalent (but *potentially enormous*) DFA that does the same thing..". A DFA may need up to 2^n states for a NFA with n states.

Answer (score 3):

DFA are powerful and they are definite, unlike NFA. But when you are given a problem it is very easy to create the solution using NFA since you don't have to handle everything. But you can't create an automaton machine using that. 
To create automata you need DFA. 
It's not very difficult to convert from NFA to DFA. But to directly approach DFA is very tough. You can obviously do it, but it's not that easy. Hence we have NFA to first approach the problem and then when we choose to make the automata we convert that NFA to DFA and then create the machine, which is far more easier according to me.